# dialog zoom effect jquery

Tags: jquery, lightbox, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-animate

is it possible to re-create a zoom-like effect for dialogs in jquery without needing to download a lightbox plugin?

i'd like to add animation to my dialogs to simulate the "zoom" effect found [on this page](http://visuallightbox.com/lightbox-mac-style-demo.html) when you click on one of the images.

without needing yet another plugin, can this be done with jQuery out of the box?  would love to be able to have dialogs (modal) animate from a specific point on the screen which the user has clicked (say a button or link) into a bigger container with the appropriate content - a zoom overlay effect?

any help is greatly appreciated...

### Edited:

```
 $(function() {
        $("#testdialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            minWidth: 425,
            minHeight: 300,
            position: ['center', 115],
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });
         $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#testdialog").dialog("open").position();
            return false;
        });
 });
```

[div id="testdialog"] some content here [/div]

[input type="button" id="opener" /]

Comment: javascript can do it, jQuery can do it, and that is what a plugin is. as someone develops this answer for you it would be more efficient to just use the plugin. Fancy specifics like this are not included in jQuery core. that is what plugins are for.

Comment: a plugin to enable specifying a start and stop point for opening a dialog seems unnecessary...am i wrong?  is jquery.animate or jquery.position a possibility?

Comment: Um... clearly, you have a choice. Download a plugin, or write it yourself. jQuery's animate() function would help you. Or you can provide enough details in your question so that we can actually help you. For example, we'd need to see the actual HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that you are working with.

Comment: sure. code added.  just a simple scenario...maybe i'm not asking the right question. is it possible to add an effect to the dialog so that it appears that the dialog is opening from the actual element being clicked? like a zoom effect...similar to the lightbox examples. am i naiive to assume it could be done easily by somehow  specifying an effect and position on the dialog?

Comment: or is it an effect added to an overlay? obviously i don't know how to do either...not looking for a handout...feel free to point me in the right direction. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**See example of the following here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HDmff/)

One way you can accomplish this is to perform the transition you desire and then open the dialog in the callback function at the end of the animation.  So, let's say you have an unordered list of equal sized thumbnails, you can make a `div` that's a white box and use jQuery to position it over whichever thumbnail you click.  You'd then begin an animation towards the center of the viewport, and perhaps resize the div, and then in the callback at the end of this animation you can launch the dialog pro grammatically.  I'm not too familiar with jQuery UI dialog, so you'll have to read the API docs for how to do this.

```js
$('ul li').click(function(e) {
  var $t = $('#transition'),
    to = $(this).offset(),
    td = $(document);

  $t.children('div').css({
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  });
  $t.css({
    top: to.top + 50,
    left: to.left + 50,
    display: 'block'
  }).animate({
    top: td.height() / 2,
    left: td.width() / 2
  }, 600, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      top: '-=75',
      left: '-=50'
    }, 600);
    $(this).children('div').animate({
      width: 250,
      height: 200
    }, 600, function() {
      // open dialog here
    });
  });
});

$('#transition').click(function(e) {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
body { background: #ace; font: 12px/1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

ul li { background:#fff; margin:5px; width:100px; height:100px; float:left; }

#transition {
    background:transparent;
    display:none;
    position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:50;
}
#transition > div {
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #666;
    margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;
    width:100px; height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>thumb</li>
  <li>thumb</li>
  <li>thumb</li>
  <li>thumb</li>
  <li>thumb</li>
  <li>thumb</li>
  <li>thumb</li>
  <li>thumb</li>
  <li>thumb</li>
</ul>
<div id="transition">
  <div>zoom effect
    <div></div>
```

Comment: thanks so much. i doctored yours up a bit, but it's almost exactly what i was looking for. appreciate the time you took. <http://jsfiddle.net/HDmff/50/>